# Rest api create sharepoint list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, choice-field, person

i am writing code where i am updating rows from excel for which i have used REST api but few of my column in sharepoint are choice , persongroup,date type, when i am trying to create item for that its no working below is sample code:

```
        function createEmployeeDetailsListItem(excelRow) {
            $.ajax
                ({
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify
                    ({
                        __metadata:
                        {
                            type: "SP.Data.E2EVMVulnerabilitiesMappingMasterListItem"
                        },
                           Title: excelRow["Title"],
                           ID:excelRow["ID"],
                           DateCol:excelRow[""], //Datecolumn
                           PersonGroupCol:excelRow[""], //Persongroupcolumn
                           ChoiceCol:excelRow[""] //Choicecolumn

                    }),
                    headers:
                    {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                        "X-HTTP-Method": "POST"
                    },
                    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                        console.log("success");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log("error");
                    }
                });
        }
```

Comment: For date column you will need data in `mm/dd/yyyy` format, for Person or Group field you will need ID you person/group and for choice column (single selection) you can pass string like "MyChoice".

Comment: Check my answer given [here]. Person or Group fields works same as lookup columns while updating values using REST. For Multiple selection choice fields check my answer given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/267789/sharepoint-multiselect-choice-field-saving-using-pnpjs/267791#267791).

Comment: thank you let me check this

Comment: it worked for date and choice column , but in my excel i have user email id how to insert them in people picker column ,user email may differ for each line item

Comment: For each email ID you need to fetch its sharepoint user ID using REST API or something. And then use that ID to add in person or group field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the updated sample code as below:

If you have single selection for User and Group field and for Choice field then create data as given below

```
function createEmployeeDetailsListItem(excelRow) {
var data = {
    __metadata: {
        type: "SP.Data.E2EVMVulnerabilitiesMappingMasterListItem"
    },
    Title: excelRow["Title"],
    ID: excelRow["ID"],
    DateCol: new Date(excelRow["Datecolumn"]).toISOString(), //Datecolumn
    PersonGroupColId: excelRow["Persongroupcolumn"], //here you need to set the Id of the Group or a User (For single user or group selection)
    ChoiceCol: excelRow["Choicecolumn"] //Choicecolumn, here you need to set you Choice as a Stirng "Choice 1" (Only work for single Choice selection)
}

$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "X-HTTP-Method": "POST"
    },
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        console.log("success");
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("error");
    }
});}
```

If you have Multi selection for User and Group field and for Choice field then create data as given below

```
function createEmployeeDetailsListItem(excelRow) {
var data = {
    __metadata: {
        type: "SP.Data.E2EVMVulnerabilitiesMappingMasterListItem"
    },
    Title: excelRow["Title"],
    ID: excelRow["ID"],
    DateCol: new Date(excelRow["Datecolumn"]).toISOString(), //Datecolumn
    PersonGroupColId: { 'results': excelRow["Persongroupcolumn"] }, //Here excelRow["Persongroupcolumn"] is array of multiple choice - When you field set as Allow Multiple
    ChoiceCol: {
        "__metadata": {
            "type": "Collection(Edm.String)"
        },
        "results": excelRow["Choicecolumn"] //Here excelRow["Choicecolumn"] is array of multiple choice - When you field set as Allow Multiple
    }
}

$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "X-HTTP-Method": "POST"
    },
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        console.log("success");
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("error");
    }
});}
```

Comment: tried using the same it working but not able to get user id for email address store in my excel from which i am reading and adding in sharepoitn list

Comment: You need to get another call to SharePoint to get the user id from the email address

Comment: var email = "testuser@domain.onmicrosoft.com"; 
Your ajax call url should be like this 
 url:  _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/siteusers/getbyemail(@v)?@v='" +
                encodeURIComponent(email) + "'",